# Modify destination object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have entity with nested collection and according model. Let's say:

```
class Entity
{
    public IList<NestedEntity> Nested { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Model
{
    public IList<NestedModel> Nested { get; set; }
}
```

and I need something like the following:

```
var existingEntity = service.GetEntity(id);
Mapper.Map<Model, Entity>(model, existingEntity);
// now existingEntity is an updated entity and we can save it
service.SaveEntity(existingEntity);
```

So while mapping nested collection mapper should remove the items which are not exist in existing entity, add which are newly created and just update the others.
How should I configure AutoMapper to reach such behavior?
I found that custom `ValueResolver`s `ResolveCore` method has no target class parameter so it can only **create** but not **update** collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for Model -> Entity mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<NestedModel, NestedEntity>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Model, Entity>()
      .ForMember(x => x.Nested, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<Resolver>());

public class Resolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var targetCollection = ((Entity) source.Context.DestinationValue).Nested;

        // TODO: Custom mapping here.

        return source.New(targetCollection, typeof(NestedEntity[]));
    }
}
```